# Helm3 ingress controller Location denied, reason: invalid format (namespace/name)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress

I am using helm3 to deploy a PHP based application in kubernetes. I am using ingress controller with below version. I am getting below mentioned error. Even though there are secrets in desired namespace it is giving this error. When I do the deployment using "kubectl apply -f yaml", it works perfectly fine. Nginx controller support HTTPS backend with this annotation "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS", but somehow it is not being recognized as shown in the error. Can someone help?

```
NGINX Ingress controller
  Release:       0.30.0
  Build:         git-7e65b90c4
  Repository:    https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
  nginx version: nginx/1.17.8
```

**Nginx controller error**

```
W0413 17:30:53.061666       6 main.go:60] Protocol "HTTPS" is not a valid value for the backend-protocol annotation. Using HTTP as protocol
W0413 17:30:56.382073       6 controller.go:1105] Error getting SSL certificate "tls-test/php-tls-secret": local SSL certificate tls-test/php-tls-secret was not found. Using default certificate
E0413 17:19:32.942187       6 annotations.go:200] error reading ProxySSL annotation in Ingress tls-test/abc-demo: Location denied, reason: invalid format (namespace/name) found in "abc-tls-secret
```

"

**Values.yaml**

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret: |
      "tls-test/abc-tls-secret"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: |
       "tls-test/php-tls-secret"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: |
      "HTTPS"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: |
  "HTTPS"
```

Does not specify `HTTPS` as the `backend-protocol`, it specifies `"HTTPS"\n` as the `backned-protocol`

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
```

is the correct setting, not only because it removes the newline caused by the yaml pipe operator, but also the double quoting that is going on between the pipe and the literal `"` characters

---

as for the error message, it couldn't be more clear: remove the namespace qualifier, since there is no outcome through which an Ingress resource would consult any namespace other than the one in which it is created

Comment: That was one problem and it got solved by making the changes you recommended. I am not able to solve other errors when running from helm. I am trying to configure ingress with client ssl auth certificate and it seems I will have to (hard code) move annotation from values.yaml to ingress.yml to get it work.

Comment: I tried removing namespace as well but it didn't work

Comment: I didn't find anything related to client ssl certificate configuration using helm on internet

Comment: If you have any reference regarding helm nginx ingress 2 way ssl just let me know. After your reply I will mark your answer as accepted as it helped me in some way.